# Office.js | excel add-in | do not allow to render data in specific cell range

Tags: excel, reactjs, office365, office-js, excel-addins

I am working on a Excel Add-In using Office.js. I dont want to allow user to render data on excel sheet from specific cell range once user renders data on spreed sheet.

**Scenario:**

1. Open Excel load add-in.
2. On add-in continue button click i am rendering header and values in excel sheet(below image data from C4:G4 and C5:G5) highlighted in **green color**.
3. Now on next time i want to restrict user to select cell **highlighted in red and green color or don't want to render data in highlighted cell.**
4. user can select any cell other than highlighted cell range.

**Is there any way to implement such functionality using office.js, react fabric UI.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can [lock the cell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.formatprotection?view=excel-js-preview#locked) by format protection API and then you could use [sheet protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetprotection?view=excel-js-preview) API and set the selection mode: not allow to select the locked cell.

```
range.format.protection.locked = true;
activeSheet.protection.protect("Unlocked");
```

Comment: Thanks Raymond, I will check above suggestion and let you know. But one more thing how can we identify the cell range once data rendered on spreed sheet how we can identify cell one row below/above, one column left/right? which we want to protect.(red color highlight from image)
Also one more thing from task pan we do have provided text field to enter the Cell ID to render data on spreed sheet, can we restrict user to not enter cell id which we protected?

Comment: Thanks, Sagar, I am not sure if I understand your question, do you mind to share your end to end scenario. what do you mean for cell id? you dont know the address of the cell that you would like to protect?